# Ребята, помогите найти детальную документацию по JS

Tags: javascript

Ребята, помогите найти детальную документацию по JS. Я новачек в этом деле, учу JS по примерах как говорится вижу цель не вижу препятствий,но  такие конструкции, например, как if (element.src.match("bulbon")) или obj.innerHTML="" мне непонятны. Может нужен другой подход? Спасибо

Comment: Детальная документация по js есть, называется - официальные спецификации. ecmascipt specification,w3c dom specification и w3c html specification. Но если у вас вот эти конструкции вызывают проблемы, то вид спецификаций будет опасен для вашей психики, поэтому я ссылки на них давать здесь не буду =)

Comment: Есть некоторое "толкование" спецификаций на mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript, но это тоже не для новичков в основном. Для новичка советую учебник learn.javascript.ru, Ну и царской дороги в программировании нет, все время будет что-то непонятно. И чем дальше, тем больше.

Comment: спасибо УУУ)) начну с учебника

Answer (score -1):

Для прояснения тех конструкций, которые вы привели в своем вопросе, вам в первую очередь понадобятся следующие спецификации.

Это объектная модель документа по крайней мере уровня 3, так как она наиболее полно поддерживаемая браузерами

[Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Core Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/)

А также описания официального JavaScript, который называется ECMAScript. Здесь уже лучше ориентироваться на последнюю редакцию этого стандарта.

[Standard ECMA-402](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm)

Проще говоря, вам надо будет обращаться на сайты [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org) и [www.ecma-international.prg](http://www.ecma-international.org) На этих сайтах вы можете найти любые редакции спецификаций, которые вам потребуются по DOM и JavaScript.

К этим спецификациям следует обращаться как к справочным руководствам по мере изучения JavaScript по доступным книгам.

Answer (score -1):

> (element.src.match("bulbon")) или obj.innerHTML=""

Если здесь имели ввиду конструкцию такого вида:
`(element.src.match("bulbon")) || obj.innerHTML=""` - то, это значит, что если в `element.src` не нашло совпадения `bulbon`, то тогда в `obj.innerHTML` будет задана пустая строка.

Начните с простого и постепенно по мере повышения скилов идите глубже.
Я сам, к примеру учился по такому методу: в начале осваивал азы, синтаксис, и прочее базовое, а потом тренировался в написании элементарных скриптов.

Ставил себе простые задачи, к примеру:

> Хочу, чтобы можно было ввести своё имя в форме, а потом вывести строку приветствия с подстановкой введенного имени, всеми способами, о которых я узнал.

После того как реализовал задачу несколькими способами, сравнить варианты реализации и сделать отбор способов решения задачи, которые наиболее лаконичные, гибкие и удобные.

Гуглить, гуглить и ещё раз гуглить (ну или каким вы там поисковиком пользуетесь). Чем больше читаете статей, документаций и т.д. - тем больше копилка ваших знаний и соответственно понимание, что и как работает. Если совсем туго и не понятно что-то, то есть масса видео-уроков на разные темы и для разных уровней, их в том-же [youtube.com](http://youtube.com) полно...

Вот очень не плохой русскоязычный учебник: https://learn.javascript.ru/ - сам в начале освоения JS пользовался им.

Когда почувствуете себя более уверенно, после учебников начинайте переходить на документации или комбинируйте и то и другое по мере осваивания. В документациях более детально описано, что и как работает. А сами учебники это больше вариант для начала осваивания чего-либо. В месте с документациями так-же рекомендую параллельно читать статьи "лучшие практики" (чтобы избежать так называемого в обществе <s>говнокодерства</s>).

> Главное упорство, а всё остальное придёт со временем.

Comment: отличный совет, спасибо

Comment: @AdelAdel если ответ вам помог, то принято ставить ему плюсик (рейтинг ответа слева), а один из ответов можно "принять" - "галка" под местом где ставить плюсики